# how to get s3Object as a file

Tags: java, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

```
AmazonS3 s3Client = new AmazonS3Client();
S3Object s3Object = s3Client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(
                "**", "**"));
InputStream objectData = (InputStream) s3Object.getObjectContent();
```

Is there is a proper way to get this s3Object as a file (eg: txt, xmls, docx)

Comment: what are you trying to do? Saving data to disk while using a lambda might be a bad idea. Anyway: create an `OutputStream` to a local file and then copy the data from stream to stream.

Comment: I don't want to save it to a disk, I'm trying to load an exel file to the lambda to some calculations on it.